# dvd-rw content check

Tags: dvd

How can I make sure that I only burned the video/photos that were meant to be burned onto dvd-rw ? Want to check in case other files added in eror

Comment: It's safe to assume that we can't guess the operating system and sftware you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to load the disc into a computer and see what's on it.

If you have the files readily collected on your hard drive somewhere, you could use a diff util like WinMerge to compare the hierarchy on your hard drive to the one on disc and see if there's any extra, missing, or corrupt files.  However, it still requires loading the disc and reading the contents.

Comment: Should probably be a DIFFERENT computer, since some of the recent versions of windows can be a bit weird with disk writing through explorer...

Comment: True, it also avoids the "laser is misaligned and the only device that can read it is the one that burned it" problem.